# Interpretation of empirical frequency of null hypothesis rejections

Tags: hypothesis-testing

assume I know a theoretical distribution that is quite non-normal.

I simulate many (N) samples of given size (T).

Then for each sample I test if the sample average is equal to the theoretical one (t-test).

Then I look at the frequency of rejections as a function of T.

Let T* the smallest T such that the rejection frequency equals the significance level used in the test.

Does it make sense to say that T* is the minimum sample size such that a random sample is informative about the mean of the theoretical distribution?

In general, what is the most appropriate way to identify the minimum size of a random sample such that I can consider it informative, given a non-normal theoretical distribution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For your non-normal distribution, $T^*$ is the smallest sample size for which the test has the correct [type I error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_I_error) (also called size). $T^*$ only tells you what sample size you need in order for the t-test to work as you'd expect. A random sample will (almost) always be informative, even if consists of $T<T^*$ observations. Even if the sample is too small to use the t-test, other statistical methods can be used to subtract information from your data

Comment: Could you mention which other statistical methods should I consider, please?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do a [power analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). There is a large literature on that, so you may want to read that first. However, if you worry about non-normality, then I would start with worrying whether a t-test is appropriate in the first place before looking at the power of that test.

Comment: But power analysis concerns the possibility that H1 is true. Here I'm just drawing from the true (and assumed to be known) distribution. Given this, I would know how to infer on the minimum size needed to consider a random sample informative (at least about the mean).

Comment: Traditionally "informative" means H0 is false, so they are one and the same thing.